# How do run an arm lxd container on my intel host

Tags: arm, lxd

Following the normal procedure yields this error:

```
lxc_start - start.c:start:1438 - No such file or directory - failed to exec /sbin/init
```

Comment: Note that this is LXC you're working with, not LXD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running arm containers on an intel host is possible using qemu but it does not work out the box and requires copying a qemu file onto the container rootfs

**Steps for a 16.04 host.**

*Assuming **lxd-client** package is installed.*

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-user-static
lxc launch ubuntu:15.04/armhf arm1
```

Should output:

```
Creating arm1
Starting arm1
error: Error calling 'lxd forkstart arm1 /var/lib/lxd/containers /var/log/lxd/arm1/lxc.conf': err='exit status 1'
Try `lxc info --show-log arm1` for more info
```

To fix run:

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static /var/lib/lxd/containers/arm1/rootfs/usr/bin
# then start it again.
lxc start arm1
```

then you can log in by:

```
lxc exec arm1 bash
```

Comment: This is no longer doable, please read https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/lxd-containers-on-other-architectures/2331

Comment: This was only doable in LXC but not in MODERN LXD.  Read https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060089/lxd-running-an-image-with-a-foreign-architecture/1060114#1060114 and the previous post.

Comment: @ThomasWard - doesn't the error message "Error calling 'lxd forkstart arm1 /var/lib/lxd/containers /var/log/lxd/arm1/lxc.conf': err='exit status 1'" show I was using lxd?

Comment: Can't tell, but I can assure you with 100% certainty that you can't launch ARM containers on x86/x86_64 architecture anymore, and stgraber who is the god of LXC/LXD even states so in the linked discussion thread.  So back in 2016 this *may* have been doable, but **modern** LXD does *not* support crossarch emulation, and if it did work in LXD in 2016, then it doesn't now.

Comment: If you try and do your commands now in modern LXD, it'll actually just yell at you and say "Not Supported" even if you have qemu-arm-static and such

Comment: This still works with LXD: https://askubuntu.com/a/1223581/1039074