# LXD: Running an image with a foreign architecture

Tags: 16.04, lxc, lxd, arm64

I want to use LXD to bootstrap a root filesystem for deployment on an embedded
ARM system from my AMD64 host running ubuntu 16.04. Previously, I've done this
with a script and the `chroot` command, but the script I was using was
error-prone and had a bad habit of deleting my /dev entries.

I have been able to copy the image locally using `lxc image copy
images:ubuntu/16.04/arm64 --alias=ubuntu-server-arm64`, and have installed
qemu-user-static, but am not able to actually launch a container from this
image. I get the following error:

```
$ lxc launch ubuntu-server-arm64 bootstrap
Creating bootstrap
error: Requested architecture isn't supported by this host
```

Is there a way to force lxd to ignore the architecture mismatch and use
`qemu-user-static` to run the child container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Stephane Graber who is in charge of the LXC/LXD project (in response to an inquiry from me on their [discussions site](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/lxd-containers-on-other-architectures/2331)):

> qemu-user-static is a binfmt helper which lets you do on the fly
>   conversion between architectures. It effectively lets you run binaries
>   for architectures other than your current one.
>
> qemu-user-static itself should work fine inside a container and will
>   let you run some binaries of foreign architectures inside it.
>
> Trying to run an entire container through qemu-user-static is very
>   impractical due to some big limitations of qemu-user-static, for
>   example, anything that relies on ptrace (init systems and debugging
>   tools), netlink (all the network tools and some init systems) or
>   thread (a lot more software) will usually fail miserably.
>
> The approach I implemented back in LXC was to create a mixed container
>   where most packages were of the foreign architecture but the init
>   system, network tools, … were of the native architecture. This was
>   kinda-working but also not particularly useful, not to mention very
>   slow.
>
> As this is effectively unsupportable as far as we’re concerned, we are
>   not providing any foreign-architecture images for LXD. You could
>   however build your own by assembling a rootfs of a foreign
>   architecture, then including the needed qemu-user-static binaries,
>   replacing any binary that will not work with emulation and generate
>   this as a LXD image (marking it with the architecture it’s intended to
>   run on rather than the architecture it contains).

So, effectively, attempting to run a foreign architecture on LXD is unsupported, and the LXC method was more or less a 'mixed environment' type of hack.

It sounds like it could also be done, but would require you to create a rootfs of a foreign architecture and basically create the 'image' yourself that runs all this, which for various reasons could be a headache and a lot of work to accomplish.

Comment: It should be noted here however that *foreign architecture* does not apply to i386 containers running on amd64 hosts - that's the only case where 'foreign architecture' doesn't apply.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get a foreign architecture to work with LXD. I took an ARMv7 image, created a squashfs from it, added `qemu-arm-static` under `/usr/bin`. The trick to get it to work with LXD was to have the meta-data tarball say the image is x86_64 (or whatever your host architecture is). Importing and running this image works, LXD thinks it's a supported architecture (matches host) and its able to run because of `qemu-arm-static` and `binfmt`.

```
ALPINE_MIRROR_URL="http://ams.edge.kernel.org/alpine"
ALPINE_VERSION="3.11.5"
ALPINE_ARCH="armhf"

version=$(echo $ALPINE_VERSION | cut -d '.' -f 1-2)
curl -O ${ALPINE_MIRROR_URL}/v${version}/releases/${ALPINE_ARCH}/alpine-minirootfs-${ALPINE_VERSION}-${ALPINE_ARCH}.tar.gz

ROOTFS=alpine-rootfs
mkdir ${ROOTFS}
tar xzf alpine-minirootfs-${ALPINE_VERSION}-${ALPINE_ARCH}.tar.gz -C ${ROOTFS}

cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static ${ROOTFS}/usr/bin/
mksquashfs ${ROOTFS} rootfs.squashfs

lxc import meta.tar.xz rootfs.squashfs --alias crossx
lxc launch crossx x
lxc exec x -- uname -a
Linux x 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:46:08 UTC 2019 armv7l Linux
lxc image ls
| crossx   | 1e5e5a2dafb8 | no     | Alpinelinux  x86_64 (20200330_1354) | x86_64       | CONTAINER | 5.45MB | Apr 2, 2020 at 6:25pm (UTC)  |
```

You can see in the last two commands the container is really `armv7l` but LXD thinks its x86_64.

Comment: Why does this work? What does placing `qemu-arm-static` in `/usr/bin` accomplish? Something somewhere must using `qemu-arm-static`

Comment: @fabiomaia `binfmt` detects the binary is for arm and uses `qemu-arm-static` to run the binary. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc